# AndEngine: UI is not updating in onAreaTouched call

Tags: android, andengine

I'm using AndEngine and I have this code for my custom radiobutton:

```
    blackRadioNotSelected = new Sprite(0, 0, blackRadio, vertexBufferObjectManager) {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()) {
                activity.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d(TAG,"touch");
                        unregisterTouchArea(blackRadio);
                        detachChild(whiteRadio);
                        detachChild(blackRadio);
                        whiteRadio = whiteRadioNotSelected;
                        blackRadio = blackRadioSelected;
                        registerTouchArea(whiteRadio);
                        attachChild(whiteRadio);
                        attachChild(blackRadio);
                    }
                });


                isWhiteSelected = !isWhiteSelected;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

And when I touch radiobutton, I can see "touch" message and it doesn't show after second touch - so, `unregisterTouchArea(blackRadio);` was performed. But UI still the same: whiteRadio looks like selected, and blackRadio - not selected. What could it be?

**UPD:** I tried to put this code into other method and everything works. That's how it looks now:

```
    blackRadioNotSelected = new Sprite(0, 0, blackRadio, vertexBufferObjectManager) {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()) {
                swapColor();
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

and the `swapColor();`:

```
private void swapColor() {
    if (isWhiteSelected) {
        activity.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG,"blackNotSelected");
                unregisterTouchArea(blackRadio);
                detachChild(whiteRadio);
                detachChild(blackRadio);
                whiteRadio = whiteRadioNotSelected;
                blackRadio = blackRadioSelected;
                registerTouchArea(whiteRadio);
                attachChild(whiteRadio);
                attachChild(blackRadio);
            }
        });
    } else {
        [...]
    }


    isWhiteSelected = !isWhiteSelected;
}
```

But I still don't know what was wrong, because previous version worked in other project. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: It may be because you are not returning true inside the if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()) block

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not registered your sprite touch area into main scene.
Do simply this .
  getEngine().getScene().registerTouchArea(blackRadioNotSelected);